Which is the western movie containing this "Indians vs. cavalry" scene?
I am looking for the western movie (probably from the 1950's-1960's, and I believe in color) containing the following scene.
The cavalry is surrounded by Indians, but no close confrontation happens. The Indians ride close to the spot where the cavalry has retreated, they put several spears into the ground. They ride away to the top of a hill, and they use the sticks as markers to deduce (from a distance) the position of the cavalry. Using these markers, they shoot a rain of arrows onto the cavalry's position.

Way too far to post as an answer, but there's a reminiscent scene in Zulu (1964), where the Zulus use their spears as markers (see it here). But there's no rain of arrows AFAIK and obviously these are not Indians.

Thanks @Walt, but this isn't the movie I'm looking for, although there are indeed some similarities between the scenes!

There's a scene like that in John Sturges' Escape from Fort Bravo from 1953 with William Holden. From IMDb:

During the American Civil War, the Union cavalry at Fort Bravo have to put up with two threats: the Confederate prisoners incarcerated at the Fort and rampaging Mescalero Indians.

You can see the technique you described in the clip below at 4:30 and especially at 5:10: The Indians intentionally stick their spears in the ground as markers, and this is followed by a volley of arrows that wounds most of the trapped soldiers.




Excellent, that seems to be the one. Thanks :-)
